# Manually change web server domain for IIS

Tags: iis, dns

I'm having a bit of an issue with an IIS web application. I copied all the application files from the server, registered the DLL files, set up my DB server locally and now I'm trying to run the application locally, on my machine. The thing is that the app checks the server domain name when you log in and my corporate domain name is not in the list of "allowed" domains so the logging in fails.

Could I edit some IIS application config file(s) to make it look like the web server is actually under a different domain name? I want to keep my machine, overall, in the current domain.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can change the config files in the IIS.

Comment: How your app checks the server domain name?what authentication method you are using?"